# Reactjs single page application - component is not loading on navigating to a link

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, react-router

I created a single page application of movies and videos. This web application has 4 links which displays different kind of videos and movies. For example 'kids' link show videos for kids, 'sports' link show sports videos etc. 
Based on link name, I am calling an API to load data on that page. But on clicking link this is not happening. Below is the code

````
// Root.js

class Root extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: [],
            isLoaded: false,
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        let currentPath = this.props.match.path;
        var apiUrl = "";
        if (currentPath == "/movies") {
            apiUrl = "zzzzzzzzz";
        } else if (currentPath == "/kids") {
            apiUrl = "yyyyyyyyy";
        } else if (currentPath == "/sports") {
            apiUrl = "xxxxxxxx";
        }
        fetch(apiUrl)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(json => {
                    this.setState({
                        items: json,
                        isLoaded: true
                    });
                })
    }

    render() {
        var { items, isLoaded } = this.state;
        return (
        <div className="Root" >
            <HeaderNav />
            <Main items={items} />
            <Footer />
        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Root;

// App.js

class App extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Root} />
          <Route path="/movies" exact component={Root} />
          <Route path="/kids" exact component={Root} />
          <Route path="/" render={() => <h2>  404 Not Found</h2>} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

// HeaderNav.js

class HeaderNav extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
          <div className="container">
            <a className="navbar-brand" href="/home">MOOVID</a>
            <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
              <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li className="nav-item active">
                  <Link className="nav-link" to="/">Home
                    <span className="sr-only">(current)</span>
                  </Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <Link className="nav-link" to="/movies">Movies</Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <Link className="nav-link" to="/sports">Sports</Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <Link className="nav-link" to="/kids">Kids</Link>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
        );
    }
}

export default HeaderNav; ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your if/ else block is not exhaustive, are you sure currentPath is not undefined? Try to `console.log(currentPath)` after the conditional. If that works, then try to `console.log(json)` before this.setState(), to make sure the json result is expected. Finally, are you sure `items` that is returned as a list?

Comment: console.log(currentPath) is not printing anything on clicking link. But if you refresh page after clicking a link, it will print in consoie.

Comment: Also console.log(json) is printing json data. But only for the initial load of the app or if you refresh (F5) page.

Comment: Oh of course, It will only load initially, because you make the request in componentDidMount, its called once. The button does not do anything, you haven't passed it an onClick prop. https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: it is a link (HeaderNav.js) not button

Comment: Oh sorry. In link, you need to somehow request the data, and set the state. Pass a helper function into links onClick prop. At the moment, you will only make the fetch request on document load. https://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/api/Link.html

Comment: The problem is, componentDidMount only gets called early on, when you load your page, and never again. That is the only place you setState, so you will only setState when the page loads.

Comment: Except adding an onclick event handler, do we have other solution to achieve this?

Comment: Since the request is done depending on the link, I would have had each Route use its own component, implementing the components separately. Don't try to reuse the component when it will be clearly different, and as your application grows, they will be very different. Then add the lifecycle method (componentDidMount) to each component.

Comment: Or, request all the data upfront, and conditionally load parts of the data depending on state.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my findings here

```
    // MenuComponent.js

    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import Root from './Root';

    class Kids extends Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <Root text="kids"  />
            );
        }
    }

    class Movies extends Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <Root text="movies"  />
            );
        }
    }

    class Sports extends Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <Root text="sports"  />
            );
        }
    }
    export { Kids, Movies, Sports };
```

Added a new component class which contains classes for all menus

```
    //Updated App.js

    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import './css/main.css';
    import './css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css';
    import Root from "./Components/Root"
    import { Kids, Movies, Sports } from "./Components/MenuComponents"
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";


    class App extends Component {

      render() {

        return (
          <Router>
            <Switch>
              <Route path='/movies' exact component={Movies} />
              <Route path='/sports' exact component={Sports} />
              <Route path='/kids' exact component={Kids}  />
              <Route path="/" exact component={Root} />
              <Route path="/*" render={() => <h2>  404 Not Found</h2>} />*/}
            </Switch>
          </Router>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

Then I am calling above menu component classes inside Route component.
Classes inside MenuComponent.js is indirectly calling 'Root' component. In this way I could ensure reusability of components

This worked perfectly for me. If we wanted to add new menu, add a class in MenuComponent.js and add a Route for the menu